# how to modify the popup box messages in sitefinity send campaign issues

Tags: sitefinity

I manage to send the issue by choosing a mail list, but when I click send issue, a pop-up box shows the issue will be sent to how many subscribers, here the spelling "subscribers" is incorrect, so I want to correct the spelling. But I have no idea where to change this message after looking into each possible page, file etc.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npoD8.png) this is the screenshot of that send issue page after clicking send issue button

Comment: So if you do a text search on every source file, you can't find this mispelt word?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the backend and then **Administration > Labels & Messages**

Type in the following in the search box: SendIssuePromptText

Then you can edit the label and fix the typo.